# Google Analytics Doesn't Work on Django Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-analytics

I set up google analytics by placing the tracking script tag and code at the bottom of the head tag in my base.html template which every other page extends from.

I also created 2 click events for when people click on pdf links.

None of the events are showing up.  Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.cs-link', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', {
            eventCategory: 'Case Study',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: event.target.href,
            transport: 'beacon'
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.brochure-link', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', {
            eventCategory: 'Brochure',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: event.target.href,
            transport: 'beacon'
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work.  The page tracking works but the events don't  I'm also not sure how to tell whether or not the js is executing when I click the links.

Comment: for starters put a console logging statement inside click handler to see if click event gets triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `event`argument to click handler function as it will not be defined in all browsers

Change

```
 $(document).on('click', '.brochure-link', function() {
```

To:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.brochure-link', function(event) {
```

Alternatively change `event.target.href` to `this.href` since `this` will be element the event occurred on

To verify see if you are currently getting `event is undefined` error in browser console